# ZXing QR Code scanning issue in Samsung Galaxy S5 - camera screen turns green during scanning

Tags: android, camera, zxing, qr-code, s5

I have implemented a QR code scanning application using the ZXing library by Sean Owen.It was working fine in almost all devices. However recently I faced an issue while trying to run the application in Samsung Galaxy S5. Whenever I click on the option to start the scanning, the camera screen is shown in green (HULK green) colour. When I exit the application and open the native camera app it is not having this issue and everything is working fine. However if I again go to my app and start the scanning the green screen is shown with the scanning lines visible.

Has anyone faced such an issue recently? If so kindly help me out here.